# How do i get this RPG to work, it's telling me that Y and N are not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simple RPG i coded and i can't get it to work properly. It's telling me that Y and N are not defined.

***https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9i4u033qxheubg/Screenshot%202018-10-01%2021.58.02.png?dl=0***

Comment: Please don't post links to code, your question should be self-contained. Please edit your question to contain your code properly formatted. See how to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide only the relevant code snippets where Y and N are assigned, and where they are called, rather than linking to an entire game

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are referring to `Y` - Python thinks this is the name of a variable, and complains that it isn't defined. I believe you mean the literal string `"Y"`, in which case you need to enclose it in (single or double) quotes, as I just did.

Comment: That helped me, I finally wrote it all yesterday